# Pausing all animation on mouseover?

Tags: jquery, css

OK so I am trying to pause ALL the slide animations on a page. At the moment I have three rows of boxes all using the same slider script, sharing the same class name. What I am trying to do is pause all 3 of those animations when one of them is moused over.

I am using the responsive slides script from http://responsive-slides.viljamis.com/
This is how I have the HTML marked up (please ignore the $smarty syntax):

```
<section class="greenBox">
<ul class="rslides slider1">
<li><img src="{$smarty.const.SITEURL}/images/vane/celebs/hamilton.jpg" data-hover="  {$smarty.const.SITEURL}/images/vane/celebs/hamiltonQ.jpg" alt="Lewis Hamilton"></li>
<li><img src="{$smarty.const.SITEURL}/images/vane/celebs/downey.jpg" data-hover="{$smarty.const.SITEURL}/images/vane/celebs/downeyQ.jpg" alt="Robert Downey JR"></li>
<li><img src="{$smarty.const.SITEURL}/images/vane/celebs/mayer.jpg" data-hover="{$smarty.const.SITEURL}/images/vane/celebs/mayerQ.png" alt="John Mayer"></li>
</ul>
</section>
```

Here is the jQuery:

```
$(function () {
  $(".slider1").responsiveSlides({
    maxwidth: 800,
    speed: 800,
  });
});
```

Of course I can just add the pause: true; rule to this, however all that does it pause the image moused over while the others continue to change of course. What I am trying to do is keep these images in order, so I need to pause all 3 on mouseover!

I have tried using the stop rule like this:

```
$(".slider1").mouseover(function(){
 $("this").stop();
});
```

But this has not done anything. Im sure this is really simple, but my jQuery is only at beginner level, any help??

The url of the site I am working on is http://vane.vanillasoftware.co.uk

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
$(".slider1").mouseover(function(){
 $("this").stop();
});
```

For

```
$(".slider1").mouseover(function(){
 $(".slider1").children().stop();
});
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/paska/NDLfZ/) it is working.

**Warning**:

Stop is the method from jQuery animation, is not a method provided by the gallery plugin. This can have unwanted consequences.

Comment: `$(this)` will stop only the one which has the mouse over it. `$("-slider1")` will cause all the three sliders to stop.

Comment: Thanks, I realised that which is why I deleted the question ;)

Comment: Keep in mind that you'll have to add another handler if you want to resume after the pause.

Comment: I have tried the above example and for some reason it pauses nothing, the logic seems right, I just dont get why its not working!

Comment: I've just updated my answer. From your code I assume the plugin exposed a method to stop animation but it doesn't.

Comment: I guess it must be something conflicting with the http://responsive-slides.viljamis.com/  script, still stops nothing, oh well :(

Comment: I updated my answer with a link where it is working just as I said.

Comment: I tried that Diego, it did not work but thanks! I spoke to the script creator for responsive slides and he said that they way they have created a pause function in there script would stop .Stop from working...

Comment: My link didn't work or it didn't work the same code in your site?? Which browser?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the response I got from the developer on github
https://github.com/viljamis/ResponsiveSlides.js/issues/95